# White bar at top of Jpanel undecorated screen

Tags: java, jpanel

[Image of white bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST7uL.jpg)

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class DisplayImage {

    public static void main(String avg[]) throws IOException
    {
        DisplayImage abc=new DisplayImage();
    }

    public DisplayImage() throws IOException
    {
        
        BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File("SP.jpg"));
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
       
        frame.setIconImage (new ImageIcon("SP.jpg").getImage());
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("Demo");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
        lbl.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(lbl);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       
    }
}
```

I thought this would produce a full screen of the Jpanel image and no white bar. I used the undecorated Jpanel function to try to make this happen but the white line appeared.

Comment: Please replace the link on the top of your post. Don't set a new one as comment.

Comment: I think your question is backward... usually you explain the problem, then show what you tried and finally you shows the results, you made it the other way around, and that make it harder to understand.